# Problem in checking when date and time has elapse using timezone

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, date-comparison

Am trying to create a date and time function to check if a given dateTime and timezone passed but my function is always returning true even when i put a future date.

I have below example class

```
 <?php
  class JobTimer{
    public function __construct() {

    }
    public function isDateTime($startOn, $timezone = "GMT"){
        $nowTime = new \DateTime("NOW", new \DateTimeZone($timezone));    
        $startTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('M d, Y H:i:s', $startOn, new \DateTimeZone($timezone));
        return ($nowTime >= $startTime ? true : false);
    }
}
?>
```

Usage
Everything is returning true, my expectation is to return `false` if current time based on `timezone` has not yet elapse or return `true` when time has elapse or time is `now`

```
  <?php
   $job = new JobTimer();
    //if($job->isDateTime("2019-05-02 12:00AM", "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur")){
    //if($job->isDateTime("2021-05-02 12:00AM", "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur")){
    if($job->isDateTime("2020-05-02 12:00AM", "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur")){
        echo "YES";
    }else{
        echo "NO";
    }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JobTimer class `$startTime` is false because your format for `DateTime::createFromFormat()` does not match the format of the date you are passing in as a parameter and causing it to fail.

`M d, Y H:i:s` matches `May 02, 2020 12:00:00` which is not what you are passing to that class.

You should be using:

```
$startTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:iA', $startOn, new \DateTimeZone($timezone));
```

Working code:

```
class JobTimer{
    public function __construct() {

    }
    public function isDateTime($startOn, $timezone = "GMT"){
        $nowTime = new \DateTime("NOW", new \DateTimeZone($timezone));
        $startTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:iA', $startOn, new \DateTimeZone($timezone));
        return $nowTime >= $startTime;
    }
}


$job = new JobTimer();
if($job->isDateTime("2020-05-02 12:00AM", "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur")){
    echo "YES";
}else{
    echo "NO";
}
```

Output:

```
NO
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/RGGNv)

Comment: I vote for this, because it does solve the question, but it is still is error-prone when passing a different format as specified in the function. Why not create a DateTime and directly pass $startOn as argument?

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to this:

```
public function isDateTime($startOn, $timezone = "GMT"){

    $nowTime = new \DateTime("NOW", new \DateTimeZone($timezone));    
    $startTime = new \DateTime($startOn, new \DateTimeZone($timezone));
    return ($nowTime >= $startTime ? true : false);
}
```

Your argument passed to `createFromFormat` is wrong, and therefore not creating a DateTime correctly. You can just pass your `$startOn` and a `DateTimeZone` to create a instance of `DateTime`

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @JohnConde My answer wasn't finish though ;)